# Gevent: NotImplementedError

Tags: python, ipython, gevent

Why is gevent throwing this error?
Running it in ipython, ubuntu 13

```
In [1]: from gevent import monkey

In [2]: monkey.patch_all()

In [3]: The history saving thread hit an unexpected error (NotImplementedError('gevent is only usable from a single thread',)).History will not be written to the database.


In [3]:
```

Comment: Are you embedding ipython into a greenlets-based project? If so, see http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2011-October/008675.html and on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ipython` uses a separate thread to save command history. Because `gevent` patches threading methods, that pre-existing separate thread triggers the gevent 'single thread' exception.

I would not use gevent in `ipython`; `ipython` is *not* compatible with gevent.

At the very least, try to patch out fewer things; try `gevent.monkey.patch_all(thread=False)` and see if fewer things in `ipython` break.